# How to responsively position elements in a cordova (HTML mobile) app using css

Tags: css, cordova

I am developing an application through Cordova and testing on both the Chrome mobile inspector and on my nexus 5 and am having issues with responsively positioning elements, and getting them to stay in the same spot when going between the chrome-test view and the device itself. The main issue finding a consistent height unit I can use to position elements using cascading margin bottoms. A header or footer is fine, it is the main content I cannot keep in position.

for example, on this random app homescreen I grabbed off google (see link below), how would I keep those buttons in the same spot.

http://melaniechoisy.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/iphone-app-homepage.png

I would imagine that it is build something like:

```
<div margin-bottom:5%>
<img logo margin-bottom:5%>
<button margin-bottom:5%>
<button margin-bottom:5%>
<button margin-bottom:5%>
<button>
```

However I am unsure how the above could remain consistent considering the following issues I have had with different height units:

I have tried using em (with the body font-size set to 12px I still get about 10-15% height difference on device compared to web inspection), %'s (absolute positioning based off %'s causes issues with the software keyboard shrinking the viewport), `vh` (same issue as %'s).
After researching this for the last 2 days, I have not been able to find anyone running into similar problems with positioning. I feel like I am missing something fundamental here.

TLDR: Cannot find a way to consistently position elements across mobile devices using cordova and CSS. `em`, `vh` and %'s change too much to be consistent. What am I missing?
What units should i be using for height in a cordova app?

Answer (score 0):

In the end i went with em for heights and am changing the base font size using media queries to help compensate with other screen sizes. Seems to be working good enough for the moment